# Writing tests for class that includes ActiveModel::Validations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, shoulda

If you're using shoulda-matchers + rspec to test an ActiveRecord class, you can do this:

```
class PersonAsActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true
end

describe PersonAsActiveRecord do
  subject { PersonAsActiveRecord.new(:title => 'Lt Wiggles') } 

  it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
end
```

However, if this does not seem to work:

```
class PersonAsJustClass
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :title
  validates :title, :presence => true
end

describe PersonAsJustClass do
  subject { PersonAsJustClass.new(:title => 'Lt Wiggles') } 

  it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
end
```

Why is this the case? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what did you get for the error message?